# unlike button does not work

Tags: php, html

i'm working on 3 codes for unlike button and i did it but i don't know why the button does not work and not show me an error!! 
can someone help me please (by the way i'm using xammp for sql) codes are below :

like.js

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.like-btn', function(){
        var tweet_id = $(this).data('tweet');
        var user_id  = $(this).data('user');
        var counter  = $(this).find('.likesCounter');
        var count    = counter.text()
        var button   = $(this);

        $.post('http://localhost/twitter/core/ajax/like.php', {like:tweet_id, user_id:user_id,}, function(){
            counter.show();
            button.addClass('unlike-btn');
            button.removeClass('like-btn');
            count++;
            counter.text(count);
            button.find('.fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');
            button.find('.fa-heart').removeClass('fa-heart-o');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.unlike-btn', function(){
        var tweet_id = $(this).data('tweet');
        var user_id  = $(this).data('user');
        var counter  = $(this).find('.likesCounter');
        var count    = counter.text()
        var button   = $(this);

        $.post('http://localhost/twitter/core/ajax/like.php', {unlike:tweet_id, user_id:user_id,}, function(){
            counter.show();
            button.addClass('like-btn');
            button.removeClass('unlike-btn');
            count--;
            if (count === 0) {
                counter.hide();
            }else{
                counter.text(count);
            }

            button.find('.fa-heart').addClass('fa-heart-o');
            button.find('.fa-heart-o').removeClass('fa-heart');
        });
    });
});
```

like.php

```
<?php
include '../init.php';
if(isset($_POST['like']) && !empty($_POST['like'])){
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $tweet_id = $_POST['like'];
    $get_id   = $_POST['user_id'];
    $getFromT->addLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id);
}

if(isset($_POST['unlike']) && !empty($_POST['unlike'])){
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $tweet_id = $_POST['unlike'];
    $get_id   = $_POST['user_id'];
    $getFromT->unlike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id);
}
?>
```

tweet.php

```
<?php
class Tweet extends User {

    function __construct($pdo){
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function tweets($user_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets`,`users` WHERE `tweetBy` = `user_id`");
        $stmt->execute();
        $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
            $likes = $this->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
            echo '<div class="all-tweet">
                    <div class="t-show-wrap">   
                     <div class="t-show-inner">
                        <!-- this div is for retweet icon 
                        <div class="t-show-banner">
                            <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Screen-Name Retweeted</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        <div class="t-show-popup">
                            <div class="t-show-head">
                                <div class="t-show-img">
                                    <img src="'.$tweet->profileImage.'"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="t-s-head-content">
                                    <div class="t-h-c-name">
                                        <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                                        <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                                        <span>'.$tweet->postedOn.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                                        '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                            if(!empty($tweet->tweetImage)){
                            echo'<!--tweet show head end-->
                            <div class="t-show-body">
                              <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                               <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                                 <img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="imagePopup"/>
                               </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--tweet show body end-->';
                        }
                        echo'</div>
                        <div class="t-show-footer">
                            <div class="t-s-f-right">
                                <ul> 
                                    <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>    
                                    <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>
                                    <li>'.(($likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID) ? '<button class="unlike-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.$tweet->likesCount.'</span></button>' : '<button class="like-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '').'</span></button>').'</li>
                                        <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <ul> 
                                          <li><label class="deleteTweet">Delete Tweet</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
        }
    }

    public function getTrendByHash($hashtag){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `trends` WHERE `hashtag` LIKE :hashtag LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->bindValue(':hashtag', $hashtag.'%');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function getMention($mention){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_id`,`username`,`screenName`,`profileImage` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :mention OR `screenName` LIKE :mention LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->bindValue(':mention', $mention. '%');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function addTrend($hashtag){
        preg_match_all("/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $hashtag, $matches);
        if ($matches) {
            $result = array_values($matches[1]);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `trends` (`hashtag`,`createdOn`) VALUES(:hashtag, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

        foreach ($result as $trend) {
            if ($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
                $stmt->execute(array(':hashtag' => $trend));
            }
        }
    }

    public function getTweetLinks($tweet){
        $tweet = preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/)([\w]+.)([\w\.]+)/", "<a href='$0' target='_blink'>$0</a>", $tweet);
        $tweet = preg_replace("/#([\w]+)/", "<a href='".BASE_URL."hashtag/$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
        $tweet = preg_replace("/@([\w]+)/", "<a href='".BASE_URL."$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
        return $tweet;
    }

    public function addLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` +1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $this->create('likes', array('likeBy' => $user_id, 'likeOn' => $tweet_id));
    }

    public function unlike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` -1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt = bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt = bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function likes($user_id, $tweet_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
?>
```

so is anyone have an idea how to solve the problem!!

Comment: The code should be here, in a minimal version.

Comment: what do you mean ? @chris85

Comment: The code belongs on SO in a code block, and should only contain the code we need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you mean like this ? @chris85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the two `bindParam` calls on your `DELETE` query. You have `$stmt = bindParam(` which should be `$stmt->bindParam(`:

```
public function unlike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` -1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
//  $stmt = bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//  $stmt = bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: This should have given you errors in your server's error logs, by the way (probably a fatal error telling you there's no such function as `bindParam`).

Comment: @richdenhaan thank you but i got another problem i put like then remove it then put again like with the same account it's give me 2 likes !! and it's should be 1 like , what the solution ?

Comment: there is no errors @rickdenhaan solved a problem then i got another problem

Comment: Where does it show you this? In the database (likesCount column), in the webpage (likesCounter element) or both? Does it work properly if you refresh the page in between those actions? (trying to determine if this is a javascript problem or a php problem)

Comment: the problem solved by u , you are right my mistake is i used = and i must use ->